# MS Outlook 365 on Windows 10 after May 2019 upgrade, will NOT let me enter emails

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, windows-10-upgrade, microsoft-outlook-2016

After the latest Office 365 update and even before, and several restarts, Outlook opens a new message PREVENTING me from entering emails in TO, CC, BCC and Subject.

What the heck is going on here? This is a continual problem where I have to continually restart my computer.

Outlook has completely changed its U.I. and that's not a problem but it's inability to preview messages in the right view pane is also still a problem.

Here's what my new email looks like...

[image]

Finally, the only solution is to restart the computer and this is a pain.  Oh, I almost forgot, copying and pasting within OFFICE doesn't! Meaning, CTRL-C or CTRL-V or Edit - copy, paste will NOT work and again, I need to restart the computer.

Outlook has recovered after several hours of being closed and me going into the Task Manager and shutting down (END TASK) that has to do with MS Office. A total PITA.

Here's the view when I try to VIEW a message in the right pane, which you can see in the screen shot, the message DOESN'T appear and when I double-click on it, this is what I get.

[image]

Yes, I've started in SAFE-MODE, outlook.exe /resetnavpane and everything else I can think off. This is really annoying. Microsoft and their wonderful offshore script-reading tech "guru's" only suggest they remote in and do what I've already done including chkdsk /f which of course doesn't solve anything.

Comment: You could try in *Control Panel > Programs and Features* to right-click Office and do Repair, or reinstall it.

Comment: I restarted the computer and it was working fine, but now, the preview pane doesn't show the emails. It's happening again!  I'm tired of this from MSFT putting out garbage and not finding solutions. I'll give your method a try, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried enabling the "Disable hardware graphics acceleration" option under File > Options > Advanced > Display? Also there are several other options to try: https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/2768648/display-issues-in-office-client-applications

Comment: I believe I fixed it with HarryMC's choice... I did a QUICK REPAIR first, it started again, and today I did an online repair. It's working for now.  I just don't under why MSFT puts out such garbage? Steve, I'll also make note of your suggestion "when" not "IF" it happens again.

Comment: Glad that you fixed it. An online repair is actually a reinstall, could be that something is wrong with your Outlook installation, maybe got corrupted during the upgrading

Comment: Steve: Add as a solution and I'll vote for you. Thank yiou